# Problem with special char in path when passing DDE message to Acrobat Reader

Tags: c#, non-ascii-characters, dde

I've been looking into a problem for some time without finding a solution to it. Tried google as well, without getting on track...

Any help would be appreciated!

Problem is:

I'm sending a DDE-command, to open a PDF document to print it silently. Problem is with the path, if it has non-ASCII chars. It would not get recognized and it throws an error. What should I do with the path string to avoid this and to get Acrobat reader to understand the path? I've tried with an "o" instead of "ø", and that works flawlessly... Thanks in advance!

```
string file = @"C:\Users\Bø\1_tmp_printpages.pdf";

client.Execute("[DocOpen(\"" + file + "\")]", 60000);
client.Execute("[FilePrintSilent(\"" + file + "\")]", 60000);
client.Execute("[DocClose(\"" + file + "\")]", 60000);
client.Execute("[AppExit]", 60000);
```

I'm using [NDde](http://ndde.codeplex.com/) to pass DDE messages.

Comment: Can I get you to try something? If you have Microsoft Office installed, try sending DDE commands to, say, Word or Excel, and see if that works. I'm trying to find out whether it's DDE that has trouble with non-ASCII characters, or just Acrobat.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment, I tried what you suggested. That didn't work either. Word shows a "?" instead of "ø". Could it be the NDde not parsing the string correctly? Maybe I should look into that. Maybe you know of any other better DDE implemention thats not limited to US-ASCII?

Comment: I honestly cannot remember and I'm too lazy to check right now, but it would not surprise me at all if the library is limited to ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldnt find a DDE library other than NDde for C#, I was not able to process non US-ASCII symbols in my path. Therefore I decided to use a different approach, verbs.

Here is my new code that accepts non US-ASCII symbols. It's inside a try-block, and I'm doing some logic to kill AcroRd32 afterwards. But the code itself to print PDF silently is underneath... :)

```
            System.Diagnostics.Process P = new Process();
            P.StartInfo.FileName = mc.PrintPages;
            P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
            P.StartInfo.Verb = "print";
            P.StartInfo.Arguments = printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName.ToString();
            P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;           
            P.Start();
```